# Passwordless ssh from Windows to Linux to run scripts from command prompt

Tags: windows, ssh, unix, password, known-hosts

What am trying here is .....

- I Have some scripts that needs to run in Windows Command (command.exe) and not from Cygwin.
- The scripts needs to access a specific Linux machine from Windows command prompt and it asks for a password every time the script runs.

How can i set a password-less authentication from Windows to Linux machine?

How can i check from a Windows Command Prompt if a Linux machine is already passwordless?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know that you'll be able to check from the Windows command line it the Linux machine is setup for PKI authentication.  You will first need access to the Linux shell by other means and look for whether or not it is permitted in the SSHd configuration and whether or not the expected user has a public and private key pair.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Pageant](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).  PuTTY combined with Pageant has a number of options for use from the command line.  Check out the [documentation](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter9.html#pageant-cmdline) for specifics to what you want to do.

You will need to generate the private / public key pair on the Linux machine.  The Windows machine uses the private key for the user on the Linux host.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i set a password-less authentication from Windows to Linux machine?

You can use [public key authentication](http://www.linuxconfig.org/Passwordless_ssh) to get by without a password.

> How can i check from a Windows Command Prompt if a Linux machine is already passwordless?

If you own both systems, you should already know this... testing should be as easy as starting [an SSH session](http://www.openssh.com/) to the Linux machine.

Comment: Thanks,
but what am looking for is passwordless from Windows to linux. Where do i put the public/private keys generated on linux machine into Windows? 

Since am using a script,